# Showing that function satisfying $f''(t)+c^2f(t)=0$ must be of the form $f(t)=a \cos(ct) +b \sin(ct)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This question is from Stein's fourier analysis which I am self studying.

The hint was: This can be done by differentiating the two functions $g(t)=f(t) \cos(ct)-c^{-1}f'(t)\sin(ct)$ and $h(t)=f(t)\sin(ct)+c^{-1}f'(t)\cos(ct)$.

I differentiated the two functions, plugged $f''(t)=-c^2f(t)$ and found them to be zero, so $g(t)$ and $h(t)$ must be a constant. \begin{align*}f(t) \cos(ct)-c^{-1}f'(t)\sin(ct)&=k_1\\f(t)\sin(ct)+c^{-1}f'(t)\cos(ct)&=k_2 \end{align*}

I'm not sure how to proceed further, I can't seem to use the product rule because the equations are of the form $fh'-f'h$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2736165/ftc2ft-0-has-only-solution-of-the-form-ft-a-cosctb-sinct

Comment: @Jorge Much appreciated